# VALIDACIONES PARA SOLO NUMEROS EN JAVA

Tags: java

MUY BUENAS GENTE SOY UN POCO NUEVO EN ESTO Y ME GUSTARIA QUE ME PUEDAN AYUDAR EN LO SIGUIENTE:

NECESITO UNA VALIDACION EN LA QUE SOLO SE ADMITAN NUMEROS, LES ADJUNTO LA SIGUIENTE IMAGEN PARA QUE SE GUIEN.
GRACIAS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL CODIGO DE LA IMAGEN ES PARA SOLO LETRAS, ME GUSTARIA SABER EL OPUESTO PARA SOLO NUMERO, TODO LO ESTOY TRABAJANDO EN UN JSP.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que has tratado por favor , revisa [ask], saludos

Comment: por favor no usas todo mayusculas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solo dígitos es más fácil aún, tu regexp tiene que ser así:

`/^\d+$/`

`\d` significa cualquier dígito 0 a 9

`+` es 1 o más repeticiones de esos dígitos.

Comment: wow muchas gracias amigo, como te doy dedito arriba '???

Comment: Puedes dar la respuesta como correcta, y también usar la flecha para decir que la respuesta es útil.
Ambos botones están a la izquierda de la respuesta.
Gracias.